# Image previewing before upload in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I know there are some answers available already but i really dont understand why thats not working in my case.below is my code for uploading in remote server.I am using phonegap and jquery mobile.Only problem is image does not shows on the page before uploading to the server.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>File Transfer Example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     
 function getImage() {
 navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
 alert('get picture failed');
 }, {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 });
     
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
document.getElementById("smallImage").src = imageURI
}  
     
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
     
   
 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey = "file";
 options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
 console.log(options.fileName);
 var params = new Object();
 params.value1 = "test";
 params.value2 = "param";
 options.params = params;
 options.chunkedMode = false;
      

var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, "http://abc.in/my.php",
           
function(result){
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
     alert('success');
 },   function(error){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }, options);
   
 }
    
       
  
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="getImage()">Upload a Photo</button><br>
<img style="width:160px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imageURI is a pseudo-path, so it might be unavailable on you local HTML page.

You can update the image src after you upload the image.

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, "http://abc.in/my.php",

function(result){ 
    var data = JSON.stringify(result);
    var imageSrc = data.src;    // e.g: "http://abc.in/picture.jpg"
    document.getElementById("smallImage").src = imageSrc;
 },
```

HTTP URL should work.

Comment: Thanks it works but how i to do it everytime for new ulpoaded images ,because its shows only linked image ,i want to display images as soon as i upload it to server one by one ,please help

Answer (score 0):

After 3 day's i got a solution for my query,problem is simulator,test below code with apk file.Do not waste time on testing simulator's.It won't preview image.
Below code is working for previewing image before upload.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Submit form</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}


// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
 function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

    // Show the selected image
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = imageURI;
}


  // A button will call this function
  //
 function getPhoto() {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
  }

    
  function uploadPhoto() {

    //selected photo URI is in the src attribute (we set this on getPhoto)
    var imageURI = document.getElementById('smallImage').getAttribute("src");
    if (!imageURI) {
        alert('Please select an image first.');
        return;
    }

    //set upload options
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    options.params = {
        firstname: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
        lastname: document.getElementById("lastname").value
    }


    options.headers = {
      Connection: "close"
    };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://abc.in/savepng.php"), win, fail,

 options);
}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function onFail(message) {
  console.log('Failed because: ' + message);alert('success');
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    alert("Response =" + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="getPhoto();">Select Photo:</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" /><br>

<form id="regform">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="uploadPhoto();">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```